# Unable to get value/text from HTML Dom. I have used getAttribute() and getText() from Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver, dom, testng

I have tried to get text/value from Html Dom by using getAttribute(); and getText(); from WebDriver but i didn't get any value into console. Plz help me get rid of this issue.In the mentioned image developers didn't provide any Value attribute to get text.

[image]

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow! Please post your code so we can help you and reproduce your problem. Also recommended to read: [Tips for asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `<input>` elements store the user-entered text in a property named **`value`**, which is also why you need e.g. `<input type="text" value="foo">` if you want to fill the value for the user. --- What do you mean by *"they didn't provide any Value attribute"*? You only need to specify the `value="foo"` if you want to pre-fill the input field. The property always exists, even if not specified in the HTML.

Comment: You should still be able to get the value using `element.value;`? Try typing `$0.value` in the console

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the value of an element you can do it by

```
document.getElementById("Sal").value
```